# How to set more than one alarms at a time from database by using thread in android?

Tags: android, database, alarmmanager

I am making a small app where I have to set alarm from database but my code is not working !! i got a black screen for 1 minutes and then stop 
How to set more than one alarms at a time in android? why my code bug !!??

```
 private void ringalarms(){
    final Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();
    final ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.context, Alarm_Receiver.class);
    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do stuff here!
            Log.d("i ammm heeere in runn", "yep iam here");
            //display();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int  hr,mt,iddata= 0;
                    while (true) {
                        data.moveToFirst();
                        while (!data.isAfterLast()) {
                            hr = Integer.parseInt(data.getString(0));
                            mt = Integer.parseInt(data.getString(1));
                            iddata = Integer.parseInt(data.getString(2));
                            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);
                            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mt);
                            myIntent.putExtra("extra", "yes");
                            //myIntent.putExtra("id", i);
                            pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Add_Alarm.this, iddata, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pending_intent);
                            data.moveToNext();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

Comment: Maybe because you are running an infinite loop in your `UI` thread?

Comment: actually i want to check my database always that why i used a infinite while

Comment: You are already using an `scheduleTaskExecutor` that will run every 5 sec. That alone can help you check you database.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an infinite loop with `while(true)` that never ends which results in app being forced to close. You can remove the while loop.

Also this code will end in an `Alarm` being set every 5 seconds or so. Probably a bad design.

```
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do stuff here!
        Log.d("i ammm heeere in runn", "yep iam here");
        //display();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int  hr,mt,iddata= 0;

                    data.moveToFirst();
                    while (!data.isAfterLast()) {
                        hr = Integer.parseInt(data.getString(0));
                        mt = Integer.parseInt(data.getString(1));
                        iddata = Integer.parseInt(data.getString(2));
                        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mt);
                        myIntent.putExtra("extra", "yes");
                        //myIntent.putExtra("id", i);
                        pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Add_Alarm.this, iddata, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pending_intent);
                        data.moveToNext();
                    }
                }


        });

    }
}, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```